# Highlight search terms while maintaining original case

Tags: java

I have two strings, one a search result and the other a list of search terms. I want to highlight the search terms. My issue is the text which is replaced, is replaced by the search term and it's matching case. I'd like to keep the search result in the original case.

```
String textToBeHighlighted = "apples and oranges";  
String searchString = "APPles"; 

String[] searchTerms = searchString.split(" ");
            
for (String term : searchTerms) {
    // Create a regular expression pattern to match the search term
    String pattern = "(?i)\\b" + term + "\\b";
    // Wrap the search term in HTML bold tags               
    String replacement = "<b>" + term + "</b>";
    
    // Replace each occurrence of the search term with bolded text
    textToBeHighlighted = textToBeHighlighted.replaceAll(pattern, replacement);
}
            
System.out.println(textToBeHighlighted);
```

Desired result: `"<b>apples</b> and oranges"`

Actual result: `"<b>APPles</b> and oranges"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reference a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) in the replacement instead of using the search term itself:

```
// Create a regular expression pattern to match the search term
String pattern = "(?i)\\b(" + Pattern.quote(term) + ")\\b";
// Wrap the found term in HTML bold tags               
String replacement = "<b>$1</b>";
```

Output:

```
<b>apples</b> and oranges
```

Note that I also wrapped the search term in `Pattern.quote()` in case it contains special characters.

Comment: thank you. I wouldn't have come up with that